# Piping stream to a variable!? or ....?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stream

What are my options to pipe stream to a variable? Based on this [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) the examples of writable stream include:

- http requests, on the client
- http responses, on the server fs write
- streams zlib streams
- crypto streams
- tcp sockets
- child process stdin
- process.stdout, process.stderr

So does it mean I cannot pipe stream to a variable to process it? In fact I dont want to save the stream on my disk, so what is the best way to pipe all of the streams and use that data?

Thanks please let me know if you need more clarification!

Comment: You can pipe a stream to a variable, but pipe is generally used to pipe the stream to some other method that can utilize the stream, if you just want the data in a variable there are events for that, like `on('data')` etc

Comment: Thanks man! and is there any difference between on('data') and on('readable')?

Comment: Both events are described in the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_readable), but the difference is somewhat cryptic, `readable` fires when the stream is, well, readable, while data apparently fires when there's data. What the specific differences are, I don't know !

Comment: Would you mind adding your answer and I mark it as an answer for future reference; it can be usefull for people who are new to Node.JS/JavaScript like me! And thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably can pipe a stream to a variable, but `pipe` is generally used to pipe the stream to some other method that can utilize the stream, as `pipe` pulls all the data out of a readable stream, and writes it to the supplied destination, automatically managing the flow so that the destination is not overwhelmed by a fast readable stream.

For instance, piping a stream to a file

```
someReadableStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("result.json"));
```

If you just want the data in a variable, there are events for that, that are probably easier to use, like `on('data')`

```
var readable = getReadableStreamSomehow(),
    result   = '';

readable.on('data', function(chunk) {
      result += chunk;
});

readable.on('end', function () {
    // do something with "result"
});
```

Comment: I believe the event name is finish not end

Comment: @LiorH - both exist, and they are different, `finish` is used for writable, and `end` for readable, as in the example above, here's the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_events_finish_and_end)